# Does Rocker template support Java 11

Tags: java, java-11

In java8 we are using Rocker template with plugin com.fizzed:rocker-gradle-plugin:0.24.0.
We are trying upgrade to Java 11,but compilation is failing with the exception
**> Task :generateRockerTemplateSource FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':generateRockerTemplateSource'.

> Unsupported javaVersion [11.]**

Has anyone used rocker template in Java11,please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [GitHub page](https://github.com/fizzed/rocker), *"Rocker is a Java 8 optimized (runtime compat with 6+), near zero-copy rendering, speedy template engine [...]"*, so no, I don't think it does. You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/fizzed/rocker/issues) (if one doesn't exist yet).